# how to use plt.yscale('log') for specific values between 0 and 1?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot a logarithmic `y-axis` between 0 and 1 like the graph in the picture.
I need the points on the `y-axis` to be [0.005,0.010,0.050,0.100,0.500,1] like the graph in the picture. how can I choose which values will show on the axis?

[image: img_graph]

Comment: You should try to cut your code down to a Minimum Working Example so it's easier for us to help you.

Comment: I cut it down as much as I could and edited it

Comment: The short answer is that you're passing a dataframe into a function that has a boolean expression that is expecting a single value. try "isinstance(a, pd.DataFrame)" and you'll see as you debug that it isn't something easy to define as "less than"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Comment: I'm trying your code and this function redefines itself:
```
def optical_depth_fixed_source(z_source, f_dm, m_lens, dt_min, r_max):
    optical_depth_fixed_source = integrate.quad(optical_depth_fixed_source_integrand, 0, z_source, args=(z_source, f_dm, m_lens, dt_min, r_max), epsabs=1e-3,epsrel=1e-3)[0]
    return optical_depth_fixed_source
```

Comment: what do you mean redefines itself?

Comment: the first line in that function assigns the output of that line to a variable that is identical to the name of the function itself. This is going to lead to bugs. You can just `return` that result instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `plt.yscale('log')` to make logarithmic scale and `plt.axis([1,10000,0.004,1])` for plot borders

use `plt.yticks([0.005,0.010,0.050,0.100,0.500,1],[0.005,0.010,0.050,0.100,0.500,1])` to choose the values that will show

```
plt.yticks([points],[names])
```